# Drop Bulgarian Nationality?

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship, children, bulgarian-citizens

My son was born in Netherlands outside of marriage or registered partnership.
Father (Bulgarian) has disappeared with no contact. Is there a possibility to remove the Bulgarian nationality & maintain British (mothers nationality) only? The father has zero contact & makes no financial contribution

Answer (score 2):

It is very unlikely that you will be able to renounce the child's Bulgarian citizenship for them. Almost no country in the world allows such a thing, and those that do allow minors to renounce have strict requirements to ensure that the child is making an independent decision and understands the ramifications.  Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find an English translation of specific Bulgarian nationality law with regards to renunciation by minors. There may not even be a provision.

British nationality is not affected in any case.

Comment: Thanks for replying. In Holland there is an option for me & my child to switch to Dutch nationality but that isn't the preferred option as we would also have to give up British.

Comment: If I may ask, what are you wanting to accomplish, and why? Maybe we can help.

Comment: @SuB why not just live in Holland under EU freedom of movement rights, and retain both nationalities?  What advantage do you see in dropping the Bulgarian nationality?